# Simple way to map csv-table to json with different property-names than csv-headers with gson?

Tags: java, json, csv, gson

I have got some csv-files, which I want to transform into a json.
Unfortunately the structure of the csv doesn't match the desired json format. a) because csv is a flat structure and the json should be of nested structure. b) because the column headers don't match the json property names.

Illustrating minimal example CSV:

```
ColumnNameX,ColumnNameY,ColumnNameZ
valueX,valueY,valueZ
```

should be transformed into this JSON:

```
{
  "XZObject": {
    "absurdlyNotNamedLikeCsvHeading": "valueX",
    "AlsoNOTColumnNameZ": "valueZ" },
  "YyyyyWhy": {
     "ThisResemblesColumnNameY": "valueY"
}
```

I would naively go and make some representing POJO-classes and put in the values ***by position*** – like so (pseudocode):

```
class Container {Fields:XZObject,YyyyyWhy}
class XZObject {Fields:absurdlyNotNamedLikeCsvHeading,AlsoNOTColumnNameZ}
class YyyyyWhy {Fields:ThisResemblesColumnNameY}

new XZObject(absurdlyNotNamedLikeCsvHeading=csvLineElements[0],AlsoNOTColumnNameZ=csvLineElements[2])
new YyyyyWhy(ThisResemblesColumnNameY=csvLineElement[1])
new Container(XZObject,YyyyyWhy)
```

…then I'd transform the Container object to JSON with gson.

The problem is, when a field in the CSV gets added to the scheme, I'd have to adjust every positional mapping after the new column.

So I wonder: Is there a simple way to map CSV-columns by header to a specific JSON property? Preferably with gson-lib.

In other words: Can I i.e. map the value in column with header `"ColumnNameZ"` to property `"XZobject.AlsoNOTColumnNameZ"` in a simple way?

Comment: Read the first column first, split it and calculate the index of each column at runtime. Then it doesn't matter if you add remove or shuffle columns

Comment: That'd be a possibility… I was in hope, "something" would do that for me, while I'd only have to define a map once ("ColumnNameZ" -> "XZobject.AlsoNOTColumnNameZ"; "ColumnNameX" -> "XZObject.absurdlyNotNamedLikeCsvHeading";…). But well if nothing like that is "build-in" with gson, at least I only have to write the mapper once ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think parsing the CSV file into Objects is the good way to go.

You can read the first column first, split it and calculate the index of each column at runtime. Then it doesn't matter if you add/remove or shuffle columns

Assuming you read the first line and you have

```
String firstRow = "ColumnNameX,ColumnNameY,ColumnNameZ";
```

Parse it this way:

```
List<String> columnList = Arrays.asList(firstRow.split(","));
int COLUMN_NAME_X_INDEX = columnList.indexOf("ColumnNameX");
int COLUMN_NAME_Y_INDEX = columnList.indexOf("ColumnNameY");
int COLUMN_NAME_Z_INDEX = columnList.indexOf("ColumnNameZ");
```

Than use your newly found indexes:

```
XZObject xzObject = new XZObject(csvLineElements[COLUMN_NAME_X_INDEX], csvLineElements[COLUMN_NAME_Z_INDEX]);
YyyyyWhy yyyyyWhy = new YyyyyWhy(csvLineElements[COLUMN_NAME_Y_INDEX]);
Container container = new Container(XZObject,YyyyyWhy);
```

Comment: thank you for turning your helpful comment into an even more helpful answer!